# Best way to retrieve the url of a imageField in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using the following models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # some other stuff
    pictures = models.ManyToManyField(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    # MEDIA_ROOT = /full/path/to/my/media/folder/
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=settings.MEDIA_ROOT, default=DEFAULT_PROFILE_PICTURE)
```

Then in a view I wan to retrieve the images so i run the following code:

```
for pic in product.pictures.all():
        pictures += [pic.image.url.replace(settings.PROJECT_ROOT, url)]
```

The problem here is that `pic.image.url` is giving me the system path, and I was expecting the relative path (something like `/media/mypicture.jpg`) so to fix this I used the `replace` function, but it looks to me that it should be a better way.

How can I build the model or access the image to avoid using the `replace` method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use `MEDIA_ROOT` as a `upload_to` value.  If you want to upload to `MEDIA_ROOT` without any subdirctories then just use an empty string `''`:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
```

Comment: The Django documentation for [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#filefield)  explicitly states that `upload_to` is a local filesystem path that is appended to `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: Yes.  But django doesn't store that `MEDIA_ROOT` in the file field.

Comment: I only added some more context to your answer by linking to the docs.